# restrict keys of inner object based on starts with on key of outer object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have two string literals and created an interface based on those string literals as follows:

```js
type context = 'a' | 'b';

type statusKey = 'aTest' | 'aFinal' | 'bTest' | 'cTest'

interface State {
    status: {
        [c in context]: {
            [key in statusKey]: {
                seen: number;
                total: number;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to restrict the inner object's keys such that:
it should only allow keys that `starts with` key of its parent object.

So, as per my example, the valid status object should be:

```
    a: { 
        aTest: {
            seen: number;
            total: number;
        };
        aFinal: {
            seen: number;
            total: number;
        };
    };
    b: {
        bTest: {
            seen: number;
            total: number;
        };
    };
```

So, inshort `a` should not allow keys that does not start with `a` and `b` should not allow keys that does not start with `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type will help us to extract every string literal from `statusKey` which is assignable to the [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) `${C}{string}`.

```
interface State {
    status: {
        [C in context]: {
            [Key in Extract<statusKey, `${C}${string}`>]: {
                seen: number;
                total: number;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAxg9gO2BAHsKBeKByAhtqAHxwCNsBuAKEtEigGdhdgBXegaQhEx1wBUIjAsTwAxAJYJcAG2GkBQojhgLg2apOQAnAGa4Y0AMpNkUAN6UoVhibYAuc5evOA2gGEok2ImRoAug4WzsHWLpzcXgCiaFr6wAA8jMxs4QA0UAAGACRmbgC+OYxakgDmeRkAfAGOIbXW9BAQCA4ILAC2JBBaVHV1wHBM0i3tnd1OvVB548FTzlNTlPAIjFAAbjLiACbGyfQOO6ZYQTa7gdO4gVDTzvyCwGcTVg1NDgAMqde1-YNvn1Z5HzquAkUiGNUez2aUHef2C3xkvzqs2sAOmJAetRIqgxE0hb0Bj3hYNesOR-yc8yAA)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering it quickly. It works fine. I will accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow allows me!